# How to test each specific digit or character

Tags: python, string, function, if-statement, input

I would like to receive **5 digits** inputted by the user and then print something for each specific digit.

For example, if the user enters 12345, I would like to print a specific output for 1 first, then another output for 2, etc.

How would I go about doing this? I would prefer to create a function if possible.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

zipcode = int(raw_input("Enter a zipcode: "))

if zipcode == 1:
       print ":::||"
elif zipcode == 2:
       print "::|:|"
elif zipcode == 3:
       print "::||:"
elif zipcode == 4:
       print ":|::|"
elif zipcode == 5:
       print ":|:|:"
elif zipcode == 6:
       print ":||::"
elif zipcode == 7:
       print "|:::|"
elif zipcode == 8:
       print "|::|:"
elif zipcode == 9:
       print "|:|::"
elif zipcode == 0:
       print "||:::"
```

Comment: OT: your shebang says "python3", but this looks like Python 2 code (`raw_input` doesn't exist in Python 3).

Comment: Is this supposed to be some sort of binary-code? If so, some of them seem to be off...

Comment: All those proposing dicts, the OP's values are in range!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and then iterate through the input:

```
zipcode = raw_input("Enter a zipcode: ")

codes={1:":::||",2:"::|:|",3:"::||:",4:":|::|",5:":|:|:",6:":||::",7:"|:::|",8:"|::|:",9:"|:|::",0:"||:::"}

for num in zipcode:
    print codes[int(num)], #add a comma here if you want it on the same line
```

This would give you:

```
>>> 
Enter a zipcode: 54321
:|:|: :|::| ::||: ::|:| :::||
```

**EDIT:**

For no spaces:

```
zipcode = raw_input("Enter a zipcode: ")

codes={1:":::||",2:"::|:|",3:"::||:",4:":|::|",5:":|:|:",6:":||::",7:"|:::|",8:"|::|:",9:"|:|::",0:"||:::"}

L = [] #create a list

for num in zipcode:
    L.append(codes[int(num)]) #append the values to a list

print ''.join(L) #join them together and then print
```

Now this would print:

```
>>> 
Enter a zipcode: 54321
:|:|::|::|::||:::|:|:::||
```

Comment: This works great but how would I have the output be all on one line with no spaces between?

Comment: How would I get rid of the spaces between every 5 characters in the output?

Answer (score 6):

A nice work-around

- Store them in a `tuple` (and not a dictionary as all your values are in sequence, `list` or a `tuple` is better in such cases than to access by keys and values )

  ```
  list_bars = (":::||","::|:|",...)
  ```

  In this way you don't need the numerous `if`, `elif` stuff
- Don't convert it to `int` leave it as a `str` itself. Using this you can iterate over the string rather than the converted numeral.

Finally get all you code at one place,

```
zipcode = raw_input("Enter a zipcode: ")
list_bars = (":::||","::|:|","::||:",":|::|",":|:|:",":||::","|:::|","|::|:","|:|::","||:::")
for i in zipcode:
    print(list_bars[int(i)-1])
```

Now for a small demo

```
Enter a zipcode: 123
:::||
::|:|
::||:
```

Using the `timeit` module to test the difference between `list`, `tuple` and `dictionary` as a data structure

```
bhargav@bhargav:~$ python -m timeit 'list_bars = [":::||","::|:|","::||:",":|::|",":|:|:",":||::","|:::|","|::|:","|:|::","||:::"]; [list_bars[int(i)-1] for i in "12345"]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.18 usec per loop
bhargav@bhargav:~$ python -m timeit 'list_bars={1:":::||",2:"::|:|",3:"::||:",4:":|::|",5:":|:|:",6:":||::",7:"|:::|",8:"|::|:",9:"|:|::",0:"||:::"}; [list_bars[int(i)] for i in "12345"]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.61 usec per loop
bhargav@bhargav:~$ python -m timeit 'list_bars = (":::||","::|:|","::||:",":|::|",":|:|:",":||::","|:::|","|::|:","|:|::","||:::"); [list_bars[int(i)-1] for i in "12345"]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.6 usec per loop
```

As you can see, a `tuple` is the *fastest* as compared to the others.

Comment: Your `if` seems useless here, if `list_bar` has ten entries.

Comment: Not my downvote.  Though your answer still doesn't work (and your demo doesn't match the code): a digit `'1'` results in the 3rd element of `list_bars` being printed, which I don't think is what you intended.

Comment: I know you did not downvote. The demo is mine and is working perfectly on my system. I dunno why u are getting an error. Perhaps, I should have put the complete list before

Comment: You have `int(i) + 1` as an index.  If `i` is `'1'`, then `int(i) + 1` is 2, so you're looking up the 3rd item in the list.  That's wrong: you want the first item.  Much simpler to insert the entry for `0` at the beginning of the list, then remove the `+1`.

Comment: Oops, My bad, It should have been -1. That's where I missed from copying the code to SO. Thanks though

Answer (score 4):

Leave the zip code as a string, create a mapping from input to output:

```
def print_zip(zipcode):

    mapping = {
        '1': ':::||',
        '2': '::|:|',
        ...etc...
    }

    for char in zipcode:
        try:
            print mapping[char]
        except KeyError:
            print 'Oops, {} not valid in a zipcode!'.format(char)


zipcode = raw_input('Enter a zipcode: ')
print_zip(zipcode)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create a dictionary for this, and then access its elements using a `.get`:

```
def print_for_zipcode():
    zipcode = raw_input("Enter a zipcode: ")
    relationship = {"1": ":::||",
        "2": "::|:|",
        "3": "::||:",
        "4": ":|::|",
        "5": ":|:|:",
        "6": ":||::",
        "7": "|:::|",
        "8": "|::|:",
        "9": "|:|::",
        "0": "||:::"}
    for ch in zipcode:
        print relationship.get(ch, "Not Found")
```

An actual run would work something like this:

```
>>> print_for_zipcode()
Enter a zipcode: 123412
:::||
::|:|
::||:
:|::|
:::||
::|:|
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterate and then perform the function on each item in the string:

```
def something(zipcode):
    if zipcode == 1:
       print ":::||"
    elif zipcode == 2:
           print "::|:|"
    elif zipcode == 3:
           print "::||:"
    elif zipcode == 4:
           print ":|::|"
    elif zipcode == 5:
           print ":|:|:"
    elif zipcode == 6:
           print ":||::"
    elif zipcode == 7:
           print "|:::|"
    elif zipcode == 8:
           print "|::|:"
    elif zipcode == 9:
           print "|:|::"
    elif zipcode == 0:
           print "||:::"

for letter in raw_input():
    something(int(letter))
```

Comment: you might need to convert the letter to an int based on your switch statement.